# Pasting code from Visual Studio into Excel replaces spaces with a different whitespace character

Tags: excel, whitespace

This is not really a question, more an answer to a problem someone else might have in the future, and it was a pain to work out what the problem was. I guess this is an okay place to put it.

If you copy code from visual studio into an excel cell, then it will replace spaces with other white space characters. This means that when you try to compare against it later, or look it up in a dictionary, it will not match/find it.

It's actually an Excel issue.

Is there a way to turn this behavior off?!

Comment: Use the [CODE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CODE-function-C32B692B-2ED0-4A04-BDD9-75640144B928) (or newer UNICODE) and [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD) functions to determine what character it is. Tell us what CODE returns.

Comment: It turns it from a regular space into a [NO-Break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A0/index.htm). :/

Comment: OK, so it changes from `Chr(32)` to `CHAR(160)`. I don't know why it would do that; do you have a rogue spelling correction? Non-breaking spces usually show up when copying content from a web page, not the VBE.

Comment: For me it changes it from 32 to 160. Given that the decomposition of 160 is `<noBreak> SPACE`, it could be that it is actualyl just adding the `<noBreak>`